# c# get first instance of string

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string with carriage returns in it I separate them using the following split:

```
 string[] RemoveEmptySpace = result.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

so it becomes like this:

```
Server:  xxx
Address:  xxx.xxx.11.10

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    test.com
Address:  xxx.xxx.888.555
```

now my question is how do i get the first instance of Address numbers only not the text e.g.'xxx.xxx.11.10'? the string comes from nslookup so it is dynamic the position may change...

Thanks

Comment: Split every splitted item again with `:  ` as separator and take the second part.

Comment: `string address = RemoveEmptySpace[1].Replace("Address:", "").Trim();`

Comment: The example string above, is this always the same? Or can I assume that it could be any collection of strings with IP addresses?

Comment: it could change at any time because i'm taking the returned value from cmd nslookup command

Comment: @Sam1 then please put in the question the different formats that the output might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the collection of strings you got from the split, and parse those beginning with "Address". i.e. something like this:

```
string[] RemoveEmptySpace = ...;

// ...
foreach (string line in RemoveEmptySpace)
{
    if (line.StartsWith("Address:"))
    {
        string[] segments = line.Split(new char[1] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Use the second segment, as this should be the value
        string value = segments[1].Trim();

        // Note: You now have the string representation of the Address numbers.

        // Stop searching for more addresses
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i was thinking too but the value will contain second Address if there is one...

Comment: Just break out of the operation once you have hit the first Address. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just break the string in two parts (i.e., apply the `Split(...)` function again on the created strings).

```
string[] add= arrayStr[1].Split(':');
Console.WriteLine("address" + add[1]); // TODO: verify syntax
```

Comment: yea i can do that but what if the second position array is some other string cuz the string comes from running nslookup in cmd command and it may change

Comment: If you check the first part (`add[0]`) is "Address" then you can tell if it's the string you want or not.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are your friend. Assuming your result always contains the phrase `"Address:  nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn"`, you can simply do:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(result, "Address\\:\\s*(\\d+(\\.\\d+)+)");
if (m.Success) {
   string address = m.Groups[1];    // m.Groups[1] returns the dotted address part
}
```

You could perform a match for each element in your array, but it's probably easier just to use the `result` string.

Comment: +1 You could make the regexp more readable by prefixing the string with `@` and removing the double-backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

After you do the split, do this:

```
var firstAddress =
    (from line in RemoveEmptySpace 
    let split = line.Split(new[] { ':' })
    where split[0] == "Address"
    select split[1]).First();
```

(you may need to add `using System.Linq;` at the beginning of the file for this to work)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array `RemoveEmptySpace`

Check, if the string at current index, StartsWith 'Address:'

if yes, split it with `:` and fetch value at index `[1]`

`break` the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the split approach, you can use a regular expression:

```
Regex addrParser = new Regex(@"Address:\s+([\d\.]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string address = null;
if (addrParser.IsMatch(result)) {
    address = addrParser.Match(result).Groups[1].Value;
}
```

This works as intended:

```
r = new Regex(@"Address:\s+([\d\.]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline);  
r.IsMatch("Address:   123.456.888.555"); // true
```

It is useful to look into a cheat sheet: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: Really? When did C# start supporting New (with a capital N)? Your backslashes are also horribly wrong. If you're going to provide code, at least make sure it has a valid syntax. -1

Comment: @adelphus I added the missing `@`, corrected the `new` typo, and improved the Regex. Thanks for the comment, but perhaps you could be a bit more friendly in the future. :)

Comment: Ah, I do try. For now I will be content with the knowledge that even after your second attempt, the code is still hopelessly uncompilable.

Comment: @adelphus I forgot to rename the last `regex` var to addrParser, but otherwise the code works as advertised. And your reaction is hubris? Grow up.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
static String getAddress(String[] Haystack)
{
    foreach(String line in Haystack)
    {
        if(line.Substring(0, 8) == "Address:")
            return line.Substring(10);
    }
    return "";
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
getAddress(RemoveEmptySpace)
```